# Using NCalc in Visual Studio 2010 - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ncalc

As the title states, I need to use NCalc in Visual Studio 2010. I am writing a program that will calculate a multi-step math problem in VB, but I'm not quite sure how I'd use NCalc. The user inputs a math problem into a text box, then clicks a button which will tell the program to calculate the answer. I've already added NCalc as a reference, and imported it into the project, I'm just not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add, at the top of your file:

```
using NCalc.Domain;
```

You could then write something in a button press like:

```
Expression exp = new Expression(textBox1.Text); // Get the text box text
try
{
    object result = exp.Evaluate();
    textBox2.Text = result.ToString(); // Place the "answer"
}
catch(EvaluationException e)
{
    // This happens if the user enters a "bad" expression
    textBox2.Text = "Unable to compute: " + e.Message;
}
```

For details, see the [examples on NCalc's homepage](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=description&referringTitle=Home).